# Vagrant r10k not installing modules from PuppetFile Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision, vagrant-plugin

I run Vagrant under Windows 10, provisioning it with puppets. I need some modules from forge, so I've added Puppet file and installed [vagrant r10k plugin](https://github.com/jantman/vagrant-r10k) with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-r10k`

First, I tried puppet modules, so my Puppetfile looked like:

```
forge 'http://forge.puppetlabs.com'
mod 'stankevich/python'
mod 'saz/locales'
```

I had to install vagrant plugin puppet as well with `vagrant plugin install puppet` . However, when I run `vagrant up mymachine` I get:

```
==> mymachine: vagrant-r10k: Beginning r10k deploy of puppet modules into c:/test/puppet/vendor using c:/test/puppet/Puppetfile
INFO     -> Loading modules from Puppetfile into queue
INFO     -> Deploying locales into c:/test/puppet/vendor
ERROR    -> Task #<R10K::Task::Module::Sync:0x5afab00> failed while running: Permission denied - puppet module --modulepath c:/test/puppet/vendor --color false install --force saz/locales
INFO     -> Deploying python into c:/test/puppet/vendor
ERROR    -> Task #<R10K::Task::Module::Sync:0x5afab30> failed while running: Permission denied - puppet module --modulepath c:/test/puppet/vendor --color false install --force stankevich/python
RuntimeError: Permission denied - puppet module --modulepath c:/test/puppet/vendor --color false install --force saz/locales
```

Not giving up, I tried to use repositories instead, so my Puppetfile looks like:

```
mod 'locales',
  :git => "https://github.com/saz/puppet-locales.git"

mod 'python',
  :git => "https://github.com/stankevich/puppet-python.git"
```

This time, I get:

```
==> mymachine: Invalid syntax in Puppetfile at c:/test/puppet/Puppetfile
NilClass:
```

I run everything from command line, tried both normal and administrator mode. Vagrant version: 1.8.6

Comment: Your Puppetfile has ok syntax and the provisioner should be running with correct permissions, so these errors indicate something insidious occurring within your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if anyone has such problem:

1. Install the newest version of Vagrant
2. Find gem inside Vagrant path (usually `c:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin>`)
3. Follow steps given here: http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/
4. Install plugins as given in question.